# Silverlight is out-of-browser setup

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, installation, client-server, out-of-browser

I would like to know if OOB feature can be set during server side installation?

For example: My silverlight application has an installer via installshield application, just in case I place an option for OOB. Is it possible for OOB silent install? or OOB is only for client side?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can do it easily with Silverlight 4.0.  in the sllauncher.exe, you now have a ***/install*** function.  Check the detailed step by step here :

http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1879-silverlight-4-installing-out-of-browser.aspx